# Eagle Cad - redefining terminals of a component

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I use default BC337 transistor from the eagle-cad's library, terminals are: 1- Emitter, 2 Base, 3 Collector. however, datasheet of the BC337 that I am using defines the terminals differently 1 collector; 2 base; 3 emitter.

how is it possible to redefine the terminals of the component on Eagle Cad 6.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, open the library, go to library->device. Find the device. On bottom right hit new, select the package (probably the same package, TO-92) and give it a variant name (like BC337-alt). Go to connect and connect the pins the right way.

When you place the part, you now have the option of the alt or the original version.